# Can't add NG Zorro to project due to dependency error

Tags: angular, npm, ng-zorro-antd

I wanted to add the NG Zorro library to an angular project but when trying to execute `ng add ng-zorro-antd` , it throws following error:

```
code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: random-eat@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@13.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"^12.1.0" from ng-zorro-antd@12.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ng-zorro-antd
npm ERR!   ng-zorro-antd@"12.0.2" from the root project
```

I tried already using both the `--force` aswell as the `--legacy-peer-deps` flags.

Answer (score 0):

#### Before upgrade

1. Make sure Node.js >= 10.13.
2. Create a new branch, or use other methods to back up the current project.
3. Delete the package-lock.json file.

#### 1. Upgrade dependencies

Upgrade Angular to 12.x version, ref https://update.angular.io/ .
Run ng update @angular/cdk, if you have used @angular/cdk.

#### 2. Upgrade NG-ZORRO

Run ng update ng-zorro-antd.
If any warning messages appear in the console, follow the prompts to modify the corresponding code.

Source: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/6834

P.S. Ensure that your angular version matches with the version of NG-ZORRO

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add `ng-zorro-antd` to your package.json and then run `npm install` to install it.

```
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^12.1.1",
```

Save the file, and then from the command line

`npm i`

(or if there are other dependency issues: `npm i --force`)